# template function member variable

Tags: templates, variables, member

My intention is to design event callback model in network communication,the event callback includes "recv,send,accept,shutdown..."

```
class client
{
public:
    template<typename F1>
    void bind_recv(F1 && f)
    {
        // How to save the parameter of bind_recv function in _recv_callback member variable ?
        _recv_callback = f;
    }
    // bind_send
    // bind_accept
    // bind_shutdown
    // ...

protected:
    void notify_recv()
    {
        _recv_callback();
    }
    // notify_send
    // ...

    // How to declare the type of these variable ?
    F1 _recv_callback;
    // F2 _send_callback;
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    client c;
    c.bind_recv([](uint8_t * data, size_t len)
    {

    });


    return(0);
}
```

I need to save callbacks and call them at the right time, but the parameters of each callback function are different, so how do I save them?

I guess maybe my thinking is wrong, so how can I change the design to meet this requirement?

Comment: When you call a callback, you know which parameter you specify… so you should replace `F1` by something like `std::function<void(uint8_t *, size_t)>` in the declaration of `_recv_callback`. And probably also for `bind_recv` as it help ensure eventual errors are closer to calling site.

Comment: I see what you mean, and that's what I'm doing now.but I think _recv_callback is just a bridge: save the parameters of the template function and use it when appropriate; so is there any other way besides std:: function? In fact, my core problem is that the member function is a template function (class itself is not template class), so how can we save the parameters of this template function into the member variables?If it can be implemented, a lot of automated code can be implemented.

Comment: When you call the callback, you have to know what parameters are required and `std::function` does exactly that. Also, your example is broken because your callback need 2 parameters but when you call it in `notify_recv`, you pass none.

Comment: I realized that. sorry, it's just a mistake in my writing about pass none when call notify_recv.